# Incorrect duration calculation in php

Tags: php, datetime, duration

I have to calculate duration between two dates and result it to years, months and date format, but its returning extra one or two days in a month, I couldn't able find where the issue is

Start date - 01-03-2024

End date - 31-03-2024

**Duration - 1 month, 2 days** (extra two days is wrong)

The function used for computation

```
function getDuration($startDate, $endDate)
{

    if (empty($startDate) || empty($endDate)) {
        return '';
    }

    $startDateTime = new DateTime($startDate);
    $endDateTime = new DateTime($endDate);

    $endDateTime->modify('+1 day');
    $interval = $startDateTime->diff($endDateTime);

    $duration = '';

    if ($years = $interval->y) {
        $duration .= "$years year" . ($years > 1 ? 's' : '') . ', ';
    }

    if ($months = $interval->m) {
        $duration .= "$months month" . ($months > 1 ? 's' : '') . ', ';
    }

    if ($days = $interval->d) {
        $duration .= "$days day" . ($days > 1 ? 's' : '');
    }

    return rtrim($duration, ', ');
}
```

Comment: You dates cross a summer time / winter time change which may help to explain one day

Comment: How is it possible so ?

Comment: Seems to work as expected: https://3v4l.org/1lo8K

Comment: @Olivier seems like the above code works only above php 8.0

Comment: @Olivier can you check this on php 5.6 ?

Comment: You should have stopped using PHP 5.6 years ago. Please don't expect anybody to check code for such an outdated platform

Comment: @NicoHaase Okay I understand, But the system is bit older and larger, cannot move new versions soon. Any suggestion to above function in 5.6 ?

Comment: I recommend that you not present the date diff as separate units, just state how many days have passed.  This will be a more reliable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the start date and end date we pass shouldn't be a string value, We have to convert it to date format if it is in string format

```
$startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startDate));
$endDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($endDate));
```

and it Works !!!